# How to get data from web service in asp.net mvc 4 models?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been following few tutorials to get grip of asp.net mvc 4, working well beside that fact that everybody sticks to entity framework and works with SQL db, my application get the data from SharePoint Lists using SOAP and CAML query, hence my requirement differs here.

I am wondering if there is a way to push data from a service in Entity framework or using Models with service directly instead.

Please point me to right direction.

Million thanks in advance.

Comment: is your question how to use Entity Framework to access data from SharePoint, or how to expose SharePoint data to be consumed by your app?

Comment: @AndrewCounts : how to use Entity Framework to access data from SharePoint.

Comment: to work with SharePoint, you'll want to use the Database First workflow, and set up your SharePoint server as a data source.

Comment: @AndrewCounts: You mean using MVC 4? Any prefered resource to learn it quickly ?

Comment: Entity Framework and MVC 4 are related technologies, but they are each a different stack used for a different purpose.  You do not need EF to create an MVC 4 app, and you do not need MVC 4 to make use of Entity Framework.  Incidentally, for a new application, it would make more sense to use the latest frameworks available, i.e. MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/database-first-development/setting-up-database.  At the step for add connection, you should be able to use <other> and provide your SharePoint connection information.

Comment: SharePoint is a Data Source.  Entity Framework maps Data Sources to class objects.  It doesn't care if the Data Source is SharePoint, SQL, MySQL, Oracle, etc.  Therefore, Using Database First, the **ONLY** difference would be the step where you insert your connection information for your SharePoint list, which is a standardized format.  Once the Data Source is selected, the rest of the interactions are identical.  Unless you are suggesting that you already have **classes** in your service, and at that point, EF is not even relevant.

Comment: @AndrewCounts: Which driver I should use to connect to share point db ?